# Use QML Webview to Download file

Tags: qt, qml

can I use webview QML component to download file and track url changes in the same ?
How to give path to save downloaded file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in QML directly. See [this page](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2971) for more details.

You can however try using this c++ example:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Download_Data_from_URL

Comment: Is it possible to track click events on the download url , so that the  clicked url can be used in c++ to download file ?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5780). Unfortunately that is not easy either. It seems that Qt 5.0 might have this functionality when its released [link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72976)